# Python Bokeh - Is it possible to limit RAM usage when serving?

Tags: bokeh

I want to control the RAM usage of my bokeh dashboards (in Python) while serving. Is there an option to do this from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Python is not Java, so there are no options built in to Python itself to control memory usage, nor does Bokeh attempt to hand-roll any adhoc solution in this area. The only option I can suggest offhand is to run the Bokeh server in some sort of lightweight VM container that affords some max memory option, or possibly there is a way to use [Lifecycle Hooks](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#lifecycle-hooks) to actively monitor memory usage yourself, and actively destroy sessions if a limit is exceeded.